# C++ returning bool is always false?

Tags: c++, boolean, return

I implemented a Quiz Code and did a short change at the end of it to check if the User answered it correctly.

My if / else looks like this:

```
   if (answer == rightanswer){
        rightA = true;
    }
    else {
        rightA = false;
    }

    return rightA;
```

I already checked with the debugger that if the correct answer is entered it goes to rightA = true; and to return, so this works finde.
But if i check the value of rightA it's false. 
If it's needed, here is the function that i use to call the Quiz:

```
void gameOver(char field[HEIGHT][WIDTH], char newField[HEIGHT][WIDTH]){ // TODO

    bool rightA = false;
    showQuizDialog(rightA);
    do{
    system("cmd /c cls");

    switch (rightA){
        case true : cout << "menu"; menu(field, newField); break;
        case false : showQuizDialog(rightA); break;
        default : cout << " ";
    }
    }while(rightA == false);


    }
```

I'm a bit hintless. I may have some logic failure in it i just don't see at the moment.
Greetings

E: I don't wanted to bomb you guys with code. But here is it:

```
bool showQuizDialog(bool rightA){

    Quiz* quiz = Quiz::getInstance();
    quiz -> askQuestion(rightA);
        return rightA;


}
```

And the full askQuestion:

```
    bool Quiz::askQuestion(bool rightA) {

    int fragenID = rand() % this->fragen.size(); //zufällige Fragen auswählen
    struct Question frage = this->fragen.at(fragenID);
    std::cout << frage.frage.c_str() << std::endl << endl; //Frage stellen

    int rightanswer = this->listAnswers(frage.antworten);
    int answer = this->readAnswer(0, frage.antworten.size() - 1);

    if (answer == rightanswer){
        rightA = true;
    }
    else {
        rightA = false;
    }

    return rightA;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not showing the code? We are left guessing as to what `showQuizDialog` is?

Comment: `return rightA;` does imply you return the answer, rather than change a reference parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is `showQuizDialog(rightA)` supposed to magically change the value of `rightA`? (I'm assuming you're not passing it by reference).

Did you mean to write `rightA = showQuizDialog(rightA)` or `rightA = quiz -> askQuestion(rightA)`?

Also, in your `switch` that switches on a bool, do you expect any other values than a `true` or a `false`?

Comment: switch on bool is pretty funny, I dont think I have ever seen that before, let alone with a default clause for the third+ states!!!
I wonder how many pluses are for scorn value :)

Comment: @RichardPlunkett Which can never be reached (since a `bool` variable is always `true` or `false`.  But the OP obviously doesn't understand `bool` (e.g. `if ( answer == rightanswer )...` instead of simply `rightA = answer == rightanswer`.  Or just `return answer == rightanswer;`, in the actual context).

Comment: @JamesKanze It is possible to engineer a bool value. However seeing the example code, I doubt OP heard about it :)

Comment: I know, still, now i wonder is there any defense for OP? Well, if this was C, not C++, and it was old C, rather than post 99, maybe bool is a type def for int/char, and true/false are macros for 0/1 and thus it could conceivably be activated. @BЈовић, my post made more sense before you slipped yours in :)

Comment: @RichardPlunkett I seem to remember some early MS software with a typedef `BOOL`, and `#define`s for `TRUE` (1) and `FALSE` (0).  And some functions declared `BOOL` which returned -1 (don't know?) in some cases.

Comment: To be honest there is no defense for me, but i was trying to fidn my failure and rewrote the if/else i had before with a switch. Also i started programming in october this year so i'm just getting into it. I bet we all made some mistakes or stupid failures.

Answer (score 0):

Your showQuizDIalog is a call-by-value function. So always store the return value of the function into rightA, when calling showQuizDialog, that is :

```
rightA = showQuizDialog(rightA);
```

Otherwise, change your function declaration to allow pass-by-reference, maybe like this

```
showQuizDialog(&rightA);
```

and no need to return anything from the function(just use a pointer instead of a variable rightA inside the function)